# Foursquare and result limits. Any ideas how to get back all results?

Tags: foursquare

I see that the foursquare api has a 50 result limit and this sort of concerns me a bit. My problem is this

"A user would scan a item and it would find all stores that have that item within x kms from them".

Now in some categories like groceries I don't think the 50 result limit will be too bad as I can't really think of an area that 50 grocery stores even if I up the search area to the max(50kms).

However what if that item is a piece of clothing and you in say a big mall. I would think in this situation that the 50 limit can be hit.

I would get 50 results back and then scan my database to see if that store contains that clothing. Yet nothing comes back but in reality if I could have had 51 stores returned that 51th store would have had it.

Anyone have any ideas to prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a way around this that involves running multiple searches that specify slightly different locations within the same general area.

This has been answered before here: [How do I get more locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7303309/how-do-i-get-more-locations?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: I read that post but the problem I see is back to the mall example. Stores are side by side and upping the the location by a bit would probably return back almost the same data and not maybe the stores across the street of the mall.

Comment: That's a good point. I don't see an obvious solution in that case. You could trying being more specific with your search terms in the hope of getting more a higher percentage of relevant results in your set of 50.

Comment: In what way. I would be filtering by category but in my expereince most malls are like 80% clothing stores and not sure how I could filter down because I don't know which stores have the product or not till I look up the store in my db.

Comment: I was suggesting that you use query as opposed to category, which let's you specify more precisely the type of results you want e.g., donut vs baked goods. I don't know exactly what you are trying to build so this solution may not make sense for your application.